# Find function $f(x)$ that satisfying differential relation

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, functional-equations, function-and-relation-composition

> Suppose the functions $F(x)$ and $G(x)$ satisfying
>   $$F(x)=f(x)-\frac{1}{f(x)}$$
>   $$G(x)=f(x)+\frac{1}{f(x)}$$
>   such that $F'(x)=(G\circ G)(x)$, with initial condition $f(\frac{\pi}{4})=1$ is given. Find $f(x)$.

I have attempted $F(x)+G(x)=2f(x)$, and try to relate functions $F(x)$ and $G(x)$, but stuck in the composite function $(G\circ G)(x)$. Taking integration for $F'(x)$ and $(G\circ G)(x)$ on both sides with respect to $x$ or $F(x)$ do not help that much. Any clue?

Comment: Does $G^2(x)=(G\circ G)(x)?$ Or is $G^2(x)=(G(x))^2?$

Comment: It is composite function, as mentioned in the post.

Comment: And also, I have thought what if it is $[G(x)]^{2}$...

Comment: Well, they are two very different things. Which is it?

Comment: Judging from Adrian Keister's solution, I think the OP is wrong about the notation.  Most likely, the original notation $G^2(x)$ does mean $\big(G(x)\big)^2$.  After all, $f(x)=\tan(x+c)$ for some constant $c$ is the solution to the differential equation in Adrian's answer.  Thus, $F(x)=-2\,\cot(2x+2c)$ and $G(x)=2\,\text{csc}(2x+2c)$.  With $f\left(\dfrac{\pi}{4}\right)=1$, we conclude that $f(x)=\tan(x)$, $F(x)=-2\,\cot(2x)$, and $G(x)=2\,\text{csc}(2x)$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}\setminus \pi\mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming $G^2(x)=(G(x))^2,$ that is, ordinary multiplication, which was the original question's notation, we have that 
\begin{align*}
F'&=f'-\frac{-f'}{f^2}=\frac{f'(1+f^2)}{f^2}, \; \text{and} \\
G^2&=f^2+2+\frac{1}{f^2}.
\end{align*}
Then 
$$\frac{f'(1+f^2)}{f^2}=f^2+2+\frac{1}{f^2},$$
or
$$f'(1+f^2)=f^4+2f^2+1=(1+f^2)^2;$$
and therefore
$$f'=1+f^2,$$
which is separable.

Comment: Nice!  I can't vote it up right now because I used up my votes for the day.  However, I have a suggestion.  Since the question wants $G\circ G$, not $G\cdot G$ (but I know that the OP is also curious about using $G\cdot G$), there may be people who will downvote your answer.  So, maybe you can put a remark in your answer that you are answering the OP's curiosity that is not directly in the question.

Comment: @Batominovski: Thanks for the suggestion! I've put an explanation in the answer.

Comment: Note that $G^2 = F^2+4$, so you can very easily solve for $F$ first. I think OP was wrong and this is the correct interpretation.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a very unfinished attempt, but the last differential equation in $G$ may (or may not) be helpful.  Here, I put my trust on the OP's interpretation that $G^2(x)$ means $(G\circ G)(x)$.

Note that
$$(G\circ G)(x)=F'(x)=\left(1+\frac{1}{\big(f(x)\big)^2}\right)\,f'(x)=G(x)\,\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}\,.$$
We then have
$$\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}=\frac{(G\circ G)(x)}{G(x)}\,.$$
Similarly, observe that
$$G'(x)=\left(1-\frac{1}{\big(f(x)\big)^2}\right)\,f'(x)=F(x)\,\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}=F(x)\,\left(\frac{(G\circ G)(x)}{G(x)}\right)\,.$$
Therefore,
$$F(x)=\frac{G(x)\,G'(x)}{(G\circ G)(x)}\,.$$
Taking derivative, we get
$$(G\circ G)(x)=F'(x)=\frac{\big(G'(x)\big)^2+G(x)\,G''(x)}{(G\circ G)(x)}-\frac{G(x)\,G'(x)}{\big((G\circ G)(x)\big)^2}\,G'\big(G(x)\big)\,G'(x)\,.$$
Consequently,
$$(G\circ G)(x)\,\big(G'(x)\big)^2+(G\circ G)(x)\,G(x)\,G''(x)=G(x)\,\big(G'(x)\big)^2\,G'\big(G(x)\big)+\big((G\circ G)(x)\big)^3\,,$$
with $G\left(\dfrac{\pi}{4}\right)=2$ and $G'\left(\dfrac{\pi}{4}\right)=0$.
Well, this looks hopeless.